# OCR using LeadTools

Tags: android, leadtools-sdk

Does anyone have a code snippet showing how to do OCR using LeadTools in real-time? I want the OCR to be for a specific region within the camera preview. I am doing the development on Android.

Comment: If you are to downvote, then say  why. I can't seem to figure it out on a region and  this is valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an [OCRZone](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/fo/ocrzone.html) to the [IOCRPage Zone collection](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/fo/iocrpage-zones.html) prior to calling [Recognize](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/fo/iocrpagecollection-recognize(ocrprogresscallback).html).

If there are no zones present in the IOcrZoneCollection prior to calling Recognize, the AutoZone method is called internally and the image is segmented automatically. If there is a zone present, then only that zone is used in the recognition.

Here is some sample code you can use in your Android application:

```
  mOcrEngine = OcrEngineManager.createEngine(OcrEngineType.Advantage);
  mOcrEngine.startup(codecsForOCR, "", OCR_RUNTIME_DIRECTORY, sharedLibsPath);
  document = mOcrEngine.getDocumentManager().createDocument();
  image=imgViewer.getImage();
  ocrPage = document.getPages().addPage(image, null);

  //the left/top/width/height are from your camera settings
  LeadRect rect = new LeadRect(left, top, width, height);
  OcrZone zone = new OcrZone();
  zone.setBounds(rect).
  zone.setZoneType(OcrZoneType.TEXT.getValue());
  ocrPage.getZones().addZone(ocrZone);

  ocrPage.recognize(null);
```

If you need any addional assistance with this, feel free to contact our free Technical support for the SDK here:

https://www.leadtools.com/support/chat

Comment: Thank you. That definitly helps. Can the ocr be performed on live camera preview surface view?

Comment: Yes, you have to convert the CameraView image into a RasterImage. If you want to see an example of how to achieve this, take a look at the MICRDemo that installs with the LEADTOOLS Android SDK. This demo shows how to use live-capture to read Checks and it converts the CameraView to a RasterImage for OCR. https://www.leadtools.com/downloads